# Restrict access or hide sub directory on ftp

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ftp

I have a Debian Linux 6.0 server with webmin/usermin running Apache & ProFtp

I need my default domain ftp user to access all the files under `public_html` directory except CMS folder.

I want to give web designer full access for layout, SEO optimisation etc, but not physical access on my CMS folder.

I have tried to restrict directory using chmod 770. This done the job but also denied http access on this directory from my browser.

My question is :

1. is this the right method? (I also read about using `<directory>` settings on proFtp configuration files)
2. Can I use chmod 770 and add somehow apache/www user to access all the content inside cms?

Comment: can your cms be configured to be in a different Directory? that isn't under the docroot? are you authenticating with system(/etc/password) users? Do you just want to hide /prevent CMS from all users via FTP or only some?

Comment: Hello, CMS must be under docroot. By default webmin creates a user with full access under this domain/sub dirs etc. I want to restrict this user.

Thank you for your reply

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do then is

in the proftpd.conf  use the HideNoAccess   directive

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HideNoAccess.html

if you want to hide it from everybody

```
<Directory ~/public_html/cms>
  HideNoAccess on
</Directory>
```

will make it so that directory is hidden for everybody, or if you only want it for a single user, you can put the full path to the directory in there, and it will hide/block access to it.